# rsync throwing mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/data/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/’: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, command-line, rsync, mkdir

I mounted a disk at `/data`. This is empty at the moment.

I need `rsync` to perform `mkdir -p` than `mkdir` as the file I needs to be at at level 4 i.e. `/data/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/filename` when `dir_1`, `dir_2` and `dir_3` doesn't exists.

If I create the needed sub-directories manually I am able to perform rsync using following command:

```
rsync -avz source_diretory/ /data/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3
```

But if I don't create the sub directories, this command throws an error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/data/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/’: No such file or directory
```

I tried Googling, reading rsync's man page, tried using `-r` `-R` but could not make it work.

Can `rsync` perform something like `mkdir -p` or is that out of its scope?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server#22908437)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rsync` command doesn't create directory tree, so you can do this by perform:

```
 mkdir -p /data/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3
```

before `rsync` command or use [--rsync-path](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/rsync.1.html) options:

> --rsync-path=PROGRAM
>                 Use this to specify what program is to  be  run  on  the  remote
>                 machine  to start-up rsync.

Your command should be:

```
 rsync -avz source_diretory/ --rsync-path="mkdir -p /data/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3 && rsync" /data/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3
```

Here is a useful [link](http://www.schwertly.com/2013/07/forcing-rsync-to-create-a-remote-path-using-rsync-path/).

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way in Linux to create rsync destination paths is to use the '$_' Special Variable. (I think, but cannot confirm, that it is also the same in OSX).

'$_' holds the value of the last argument of the previous command executed. So the question could be answered with:

`mkdir -p /data/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3 && rsync -avz source_directory/ $_`