# mkdir: cannot create directory '{filename}': File exists

Tags: mkdir

For context I'm using rclone to copy a folder into a mnt point.

This works until I try to remount, I get the following error

mkdir: cannot create directory 's3': File exists

However when I browse to the folder it is empty, and when i try the raw command:

mkdir s3

I get the same error

`ls` returns nothing

`dir` returns nothing

`ls -a` returns:

`. ..`

Comment: It might help to add, here or in a pastebin, the actual rclone command and the actual [re]mount command that you're using and the relevant lines of output of `mount` itself. My instinct suggests you're coming up against either a problem with nested directories like in https://askubuntu.com/q/561212/29073 or a problem in how you're trying to use mount.

Comment: Thanks. But the issue not really with rclone, but Ubuntu and the mkdir command.  When I browse to the folder and use mkdir from the terminal, I get the error above.  My question is more about the file system in general of how can mkdir fail to create a folder and state because it does exist, when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had was the mount was still present, but the folder was not, to fix this I had to run

umount {thePath}

which then allowed the folder to be recreated